# Do I have to root Samsung Galaxy S4 Verizon before I install CyanogenMod 11?

Tags: cyanogenmod

Device: GS4 NC5 SCH-1545 Verizon
Android: 4.4.2

I don't want the all the stock apps that you can't delete normally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because you need to have root in order to install a recovery; which you will, in turn, use to flash CyanogenMod.